# ksqlDB find global max and min in KTable and store corresponding column

Tags: sql, ksqldb

Suppose I have a KTable with 3 columns

- productId
- timestamp
- price

I want to get the global maximum and minimum price. But also want to store the corresponding timestamp for the latest min or max price.

For instance if the data for the columns is
1, timestamp_a, 1.99
1, timestamp_b, 5.99
1, timestamp_c, 2.99

min(price) would be 1.99
max(price) would be 5.99
And timestamp would be timestamp_b

When trying a group by and min and max aggregate functions I'm unable to get the corresponding timestamp. Also tried a case statement but it will be null if condition is not met for last record.